# Add Request SOAP-Header to Response

Tags: soap, header, apache-axis, server-side

I am working on an bottom up web service for axis2 deployed on tomcat.
The processing is all working, but for tracking purposes I would like to include some meta data using the Soap Header. Do you know how to make axis2 include the header received into the response? E.g. I would like to pass an id with the header and receive it with the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to handle these scenarios in Axis2 is to use a handler. You can engage your handler to the out flow and do the header adding part is there. This article[1] describes about the axis2 architecture and how to add new handlers using modules.

[1] http://wso2.org/library/articles/extending-axis2